# whitespace in asp.net mvc views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have the following code in the asp.net mvc view

```
if (isLoggedInUserAdmin)
{%>
     <%=Html.ActionLink("View", "Details", new {id = item.Mail_ID})%>,
     <a href='/Users/ConfirmDelete?id= <%=item.Mail_ID%>' class="delete">Delete</a>
<%}
if (userRequiresApproval)
{%>
      ,<%= Html.ActionLink("Approve", "Approve", new { id = item.Mail_ID })%>
<%}%>
```

The issue is that it shows up as:

```
View, Delete , Approve
```

instead of

```
View, Delete, Approve
```

Does anyone know why there would be a space between Delete and the next "," ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than likely it's from between the `{%>` on the one line and the `,` on the next line.

I would forgo the nice indentation and deal with having tag soup by getting `<%} if (userRequiresApproval) {%>,<%=`... onto a single line.  Do this as much as possible until the space goes away.

You may also need to get the `Delete` anchor on the same line as the `if (userRequiresApproval)` statement, as well.

Answer (score 0):

There's a newline and a bunch of whitespace between your link and your comma.  You'll need to strip it all out if you don't want any space there.